# In a SQL request, select differents date from the same day to sum them

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to sum up all the visits in the same day to show them in
a graph. So, instead of having, for example: 1 visit 05/04/2018 10:00, 1 visit 05/04/2018 11:00 and 1 visit 05/04/2018 15:00. I would like to have 3 visits in the 05/04/2018 to show it,then, in a graph. My date is with this format: 2018-04-05 19:10:01. These scripts don't function. Can you help fix it please?

```
mysql_connect($host, $username,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($bdd_name) or die(mysql_error());  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT creationdate) FROM  mystats WHERE  idpage = ".$idpage." ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{//treatment of the results} else {// no results found}
```

Comment: `$idpage` is a string or integer? You also shouldn't be using `mysql_*` anymore `PDO` or `mysqli_` should be being used.

Comment: Also, do you have PHP error reporting on, `{//treatment of the results} else {// no results found}` should cause an error because the `//` comments out the closing `}`.

Comment: You want to make use of `GROUP BY` and `DATE()`

Comment: Your main problem is your use of an ancient, insecure, and deprecated API.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Answer (score -1):

To address your problem. The problem is in you SQL Query.

```
mysql_connect($host, $username,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($bdd_name) or die(mysql_error());  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mystats WHERE idpage = ".$idpage." GROUP BY DATE(creationdate) ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //treatment of the results
} else {
    // no results found
}
```

NOTES:

1. As of PHP 5.5 the mysql extension is deprecated (removed in PHP 7). See [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and choose supported API
2. Concatenating sql queries (WHERE idpage = ".$idpage." ) is not safe and its subject to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements (according to the API you will choose)